# strace output: measure time taken for system call

Tags: time, awk, strace

I wanted to format strace output data obtained with options "strace -s 1024 -vftT" and has the log something like,

```
... <log that is un-important>
24339 01:51:55 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 114 <0.000050>
...
15016 01:51:55 sendto(594, "<some log to different file>, not included for time measure", <size>, 0, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
... <log from different threads>
15016 01:51:55 <... sendto resumed> )   = 5 <0.000076>
... <log that is un-important>
29192 01:51:57 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
...
29192 01:51:58 <... sendto resumed> )   = 109 <0.652744>
... <log that is un-important>
```

-> I wanted to find the total time spent in all sendto(4, ) calls.
-> This should also consider sendto() resumed calls after thread switch.
-> Time calculation should ignore sendto() calls to different file-descriptor other than file-descriptor 4.

So my requirement in this case is I need some script (preferably using sed) to add all the timings taken by sendto(4, ...) calls (in this example it is 0.000050+0.652744=0.652794).

Any references to similar to context is welcome (I tried finding, but could not find anything relevant).

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html can do all of what you need. Sorry, but Stack overflow isn't a free coding service. Good luck.

Comment: feel free to update your question with required output (based on the sample input above) (and in the exact format you need) AND also  any attempt to solve your problem. Include your current output and error messages. `sed` can do a lot of things, but addition, grand totals would be a super-genius sed user. Awk is designed for this. A hint is `awk '/text 2 match/{timeval=$(NF);gsub(/[<>/, "", timeval); totTime+=timeval} END{print "totalTime=" totTime}' /path/to/log/file`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Shellter, Following is the sample output with the updated script...                                            `24339 01:51:55 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 114 <0.000050>
...
29192 01:51:57 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
...
29192 01:51:58 <... sendto resumed> )   = 109 <0.652744>
total = 0.652794, cnt = 2, average = 0.326397`

Comment: wow, you really did some fast reading!  But... really hard to read your current output. Why not add it to your question. Also, is there a problem? This looks like the output you want. **if this is a working answer, you should post it as an answer, and then accept it after 48 hrs to gain reputation points**. In the future, you'll want to edit down your sample data to something that fits easily on one line (per record), just the stuff that makes each line unique and the values that are of interest (with a record or two of "ignore this line" added). Good luck.

Comment: And even if this is a working solution, I'm 99% certain that awk supports a lot of idoms that should reduce this code to 2-3 lines! If I can find an example here on S.O., I'll add a link.

Comment: Storing state is the idiom I'm refering to, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475262/awk-find-if-specific-line-exists-between-multiple-common-patterns/27475300#27475300 for a small example. If you follow the `awk` questions you'll find 'stored state' turn up several times a week, but unfortunately it's very seldom refered to in the answer, and the variable names don't usually offer any clue. This linked answer is better that regard. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me, Thanks to Shellter for suggestion to use awk (though I have not considered special cases where "sendto" itself is part of data for other system calls)

```
cat strace.txt | awk ' 
function find_thread(maxInd, threads, threadStrArr, reqThr)
{
    for (ind = 1; ind <= maxInd; ind++)
    {
        if (reqThr == threads[ind])
        {
            printf "...\n%s\n...\n", threadStrArr[ind]
            for ( ; ind < maxInd; ind++)
            {
                threads[ind] = threads[ind + 1]
                threadStrArr[ind]=threadStrArr[ind + 1]
            }
            return reqThr
        }
    }
    return -1
}
{
    thrCnt=0
    totmatchCnt=0
    totTimetaken=0
    syscall_name="sendto"
    while ((getline myline) > 0) {
        found_syscall_finished=0
        resumed_found=match(myline, "<... "syscall_name" resumed>")
        if (resumed_found != 0)
        {
            # Found "<system call> resumed" string in the input line
            split(myline,a," ");
            thread_id=a[1]
            if (thrCnt > 0)
            {
                # Now need to find matching thread (if any) from the unfinished calls
                foundThr=find_thread(thrCnt, threads, threadStrArr, thread_id)
                if (foundThr != -1)
                {
                    # There is a matching unfinished call found in the trace
                    thrCnt--
                    found_syscall_finished=1
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            # It is not resumed system call, check if required system call found
            syscall_found = match(myline, syscall_name"\\(4,")  # Please note the 4, ie first parameter is 4
            if (syscall_found != 0)
            {
                # It is required system call
                unfinished_found=match(myline, "<unfinished ...>$")
                if (unfinished_found != 0)
                {
                    # It is an unfinished call, add thread number to the array for search later
                    split(myline,a," ");
                    thrCnt++
                    threadStrArr[thrCnt]=myline
                    threads[thrCnt]=a[1]
                }
                else
                {
                    found_syscall_finished=1
                }
            }
        }
        if (found_syscall_finished != 0)
        {
            # current line contains required system call which is finished, fetch time and add to total time
            printf "%s\n", myline
            n=split(myline,a,"[ <>]");
            time_took=a[n-1]
            totmatchCnt++
            totTimetaken=totTimetaken+time_took
        }
    }
    if (totmatchCnt != 0)
    {
        avgTime=totTimetaken/totmatchCnt
        printf "total = %s, cnt = %s, average = %s\n", totTimetaken, totmatchCnt, avgTime
    }
}
'

sample output,
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24339 01:51:55 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 114 <0.000050>
...
29192 01:51:57 sendto(4, "<logging to required file>", <size>, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
...
29192 01:51:58 <... sendto resumed> )   = 109 <0.652744>
total = 0.652794, cnt = 2, average = 0.326397
```