# awk find if specific line exists between multiple common patterns

Tags: bash, awk

I cant quite get my statements working as I need.

I need to find if each of the patterns called Group contain the line FUNEnable within a config file. If its present then add a line after it within the file, if not then print a warning to screen. The could be any number of patterns called group as shown below:

**Sample file**

```
#config file
<Some config>
More config
</Some config>

#comment about FUNEnable
Other config things

<Group small.group>
Something here
FUNEnable
Funfile /someplace/afunfile
</Group>

<Group medium.group>
More stuff here
Funfile /someplace/afunfile
</Group>
```

First attempt:

```
cat configfile.conf | awk '/^<Group/,/^<\/Group>/' | grep -q ^'FUNEnable' || print "WARNING";
```

This works great if both patterns do not have SSLEnable but if one has SSLEnable present then it does not print the warning. I obviously need to build some form of loop into it but not quite sure

```
cat configfile.conf | awk -F /\n '/^<Group/,/^<\/Group>/ { if ($1 == "FUNEnable") {print $1 "\nANOTHER LINE"} else { print "WARNING"}}';
```

This doesnt quite do what i need.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Is it an apache config file ? If yes, you should use a proper config parser

Comment: Post the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^<Group/{name=$2;missing=1} /FUNEnable/{missing=0} /^<\/Group/ && missing {print "FUNEnable missing for group <" name}' configfile.conf
FUNEnable missing for group <medium.group>
```

How it works:

- `/^<Group/{name=$2;missing=1}`

  Every time that a new group is started, initialize the variable `name` to the group name and the variable `missing` to true (1).
- `/FUNEnable/{missing=0}`

  Everytime that we encounter `FUNEnable` on a line, reset the variable `missing` to false (0).
- `/^<\/Group/ && missing {print "FUNEnable missing for group <" name}`

  When we reach the end of a group and if `missing` is true, then print a warning.

The above was tested with GNU `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Store some state in your awk script.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ingroup = 0; found = 0;}
/begingroup/{ingroup = 1;}
$0 ~ /pattern/ && ingroup == 1{found = 1;}
/endgroup/ {if(found == 0) print "Pattern not found in group";
            found = 0; ingroup = 0;}'
```

In the above script, replace `begingroup`, `pattern` and `endgroup` with the corresponding regexes.

Comment: You are missing a `"` in 5th line after the `group` so this fails.  When `"` is added, it still does not give any output.  Always add output of you commands (if its not too long).

Comment: It still does not give any output.  You can also remove the `BEGIN` section, since you do not need to declare variable to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty one-liner for what sounds like a quick and dirty task:

```
gawk -vRS='<Group' '!/\nFUNEnable.*<\/Group>/ && sub(/<\/Group>.*/,"") {print RS $0}'
```

Most of what it does is break the input into records separated with `<Group` and then echo out records that don't contain the right regex. You need GNU Awk to set `RS` to a multichar string.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
awk -F"\n" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^[ \t]*FUNEnable/) {f=1;$i=$i"\nNew line"}} 1; END  {if (!f) print "not found"} ' RS="" OFS="\n" ORS="\n\n" configfile.conf
#config file
<Some config>
More config
</Some config>

#comment about FUNEnable
Other config things

<Group small.group>
Something here
FUNEnable
New line
Funfile /someplace/afunfile
</Group>

<Group medium.group>
More stuff here
Funfile /someplace/afunfile
</Group>
```

If it finds a line starting with `FUNEnable` it adds a new line after it.
If it's not found it prints `not found` at end of file.

---

Some more readable:

```
awk '
    {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if ($i~/^[ \t]*FUNEnable/) {
            f=1
            $i=$i"\nNew line"}} 
1
END  {
    if (!f) print "not found"} 
' FS="\n" RS="" OFS="\n" ORS="\n\n" configfile.conf
```